# Why is 2 corinthians 11:6 totally mistranslated? By obvious decievers? Covering up Paul's admittance his satan test was his own word and not doctrine?

Tags: 2-corinthians

Hidden manna  in 2 corinthians 11:6 by uncovering false translations

PAUL admitted  his test of 1 corinthians 5:5 which was another renedy for saved sinners other than christs blood was his own word and not the doctrine. This fact was admitted by him in 2 corinthians 11 : 6 
But They covered up his admittance by a FALSE TRANSLATION

notice there is no

I am in the greek text

And  there is no

Unpolished in speech in the greek text

Nor is there

yet i am  in the greek text

And there is no

In - in the greek text

And there is no

We have been in the greek text

None of that drivel is In the actual inspired by the holy spirit  Greek text.

The false translation covering up Pauls admittance of the test of 1 corinthians 5;5 where Paul dealing with a church judging eachother and throwing out publicly embrassing believers publicly known by outsiders to have been caught sinning says
i have judged the man ( Paul had zero power to judge anyman) hand the man over to satan to destroy his flesh and save his spirit, all impossible all amounting to another  gospel another Jesus another spirit to save a justified believer . All an action for sin cleansing and even talking of need of salvation  of one already saved already justified by faith in Christ that other gospel other Jesus other spirit the corinthians he says in 2 corinthians  were putting up with happily enough considering nothing inferior nothing lacking for the sake of the super apostle
Even if indeed it his own word and but not the doctrine
And in all things he had made it clear
In every part of the whole picture
To them.

But even if I am unpolished in speech, yet I am not in knowledge; but in every way, we have been made manifest to you in all things

εἰ
ei

If

ei: forasmuch as, if, that
Original Word: εἰ
Part of Speech: Conditional Particle Or Conjunction
Transliteration: ei
Phonetic Spelling: (i)
Definition: forasmuch as, if, that
Usage: if

δὲ
de

Indeed on top of this

1161 dé (a conjunction) – moreover, indeed now . . . , on top of this . . . ,

καὶ
kai

Even

2532 kaí (the most common NT conjunction, used over 9,000 times) – and (also), very often, moreover, even, indeed (the context determines the exact sense)

ἰδιώτης
idiōtēs

Ones own ,

2399 idiṓtēs (from 2398 /ídios, "own") – properly, of one's own

τῷ
tō

The

ho, hé, to: the
Original Word: ὁ, ἡ, τό
Part of Speech: Definite Article
Transliteration: ho, hé, to
Phonetic Spelling: (ho)
Definition: the
Usage: the, the definite article.

λόγῳ,
logō

Word

λόγῳ (logō) —

Strong's Exhaustive Concordance
a word, the Word
a word, speech, divine utterance

E.g

Matthew 8:8 N-DMS
GRK: μόνον εἰπὲ λόγῳ καὶ ἰαθήσεται
NAS: say the word, and my servant
KJV: but speak the word only, and
INT: only speak the word And will be healed

ἀλλ’
all’

But

235 allá (typically a strong adversative conjunction) – but (but instead), nevertheless, on the contrary.

E.g
Matthew 4:4 Conj
GRK: ὁ ἄνθρωπος ἀλλ' ἐπὶ παντὶ
KJV: bread alone, but by every
INT: the man but by every

οὐ
ou

Not

3756 ou – no ("not").  3756 (ou) objectively negates a statement, "ruling it out as fact

E.g
Matthew 6:26 Adv
GRK: οὐρανοῦ ὅτι οὐ σπείρουσιν οὐδὲ
KJV: they sow not, neither
INT: air that not they sow nor

τῇ
tē

The

ho, hé, to: the
Original Word: ὁ, ἡ, τό , τῇ ( female)
Part of Speech: Definite Article
Transliteration: ho, hé, to
Phonetic Spelling: (ho)
Definition: the
Usage: the, the definite article

E.g
Matthew 19:5 Art-DFS
GRK: καὶ κολληθήσεται τῇ γυναικὶ αὐτοῦ
INT: and will be joined with the wife of him

Matthew 7:22 Art-DFS
GRK: ἐν ἐκείνῃ τῇ ἡμέρᾳ Κύριε
INT: on that the day Lord

γνώσει,
gnōsei

Doctrine

gnósis: a knowing, knowledge, doctrine
Original Word: γνῶσις, εως, ἡ
Part of Speech: Noun, Feminine
Transliteration: gnósis
Phonetic Spelling: (gno'-sis)
Definition: a knowing, knowledge
Usage: knowledge, doctrine, wisdom

E,g 
Luke 1:77 N-AFS
GRK: τοῦ δοῦναι γνῶσιν σωτηρίας τῷ
NAS: to His people [the] knowledge of salvation
KJV: To give knowledge of salvation
INT: to give knowledge of salvation to the people of him in the forgiveness of sins of them

ἀλλ’
all’

But

235 allá (typically a strong adversative conjunction) – but (but instead), nevertheless, on the contrary.

E.g

Matthew 4:4 Conj
GRK: ὁ ἄνθρωπος ἀλλ' ἐπὶ παντὶ
KJV: bread alone, but by every
INT: the man but by every

ἐν
en

In

1722 en (a preposition) – properly, in (inside, within); (figuratively) "in the realm (sphere) of," as in the condition (state) in whichsomething operates from the inside (within

E.g
Matthew 3:1 Prep
GRK: βαπτιστὴς κηρύσσων ἐν τῇ ἐρήμῳ
KJV: preaching in the wilderness
INT: Baptist proclaiming in the wilderness

παντὶ
panti

Every part

all, every
Original Word: πᾶς, πᾶσα, πᾶν
Part of Speech: Adjective
Transliteration: pas
Phonetic Spelling: (pas)
Definition: all, every
Usage: all, the whole, every kind of.

pás ("each, every") means "all" in the sense of "each (every) part that applies." The emphasis of the total picture then is on "one piece at a time."  365 (ananeóō) then focuses on the part(s) making up the whole – viewing the whole in terms of the individual parts.

E.g

Luke 4:4 Adj-DNS
GRK: ἀλλ' ἐπὶ παντὶ ῥήματι Θεοῦ
KJV: but by every word of God.
INT: but by every word of God

In every part

φανερώσαντες
phanerōsantes

Made it clear , shown

phaneroó: to make visible, make clear
Original Word: φανερόω
Part of Speech: Verb
Transliteration: phaneroó
Phonetic Spelling: (fan-er-o'-o)
Definition: to make visible, make clear
Usage: I make clear (visible, manifest), make known.

phaneros: visible, manifest clear 
Original Word: φανερός, ά, όν
Part of Speech: Adjective
Transliteration: phaneros
Phonetic Spelling: (fan-er-os')
Definition: visible, manifest
Usage: make apparent, make clear, make visible, make manifest; adv: clearly.

E.g
passive used of something hitherto non-existent but now made actual and visible, realized, 1 John 3:2 (

E.g

John 21:1 V-AIA-3S
GRK: ΜΕΤΑ ΤΑΥΤΑ ἐφανέρωσεν ἑαυτὸν πάλιν
NAS: Jesus manifested Himself
KJV: Jesus shewed himself
INT: After these things revealed himself again

manifest, open, outward

Made clear ; ; revealed , shown  ;  shown clearly it  WAS not the knowledge not of Christ

( i.e SHOWN Paul's 1: corinthians yeast of Pharisee test ; the judging and saving by another Jesus working with satan to destroy the flesh and save the spirit of a justified believer , one whom God had already saved forgiven and justified was NOT THE DOCTRINE OF CHRIST  but was another  gospel another Jesus another spirit ( Paul's test  for yeast of the Pharisee spirit )

In every way made clear;  SHOWN. It was a private word; ones own;  PAULS OWN WORD AND TRULY NOT THE KNOWLEDGE  , It was not the true doctrine not the true knowledge was not of christ  , but was Paul's word;   his own private word ; Ones own private word, that he by the authority of Jesus Christ in the wisdom of the Spirit had used to test them to see if they had really listened obediently to the gospel of Christ.
Because they were full of the yeast of the Pharisees concerned what unbelieving men thought of them if there was ever one publicly known to have sinned which is hypocrisy.

ἐν
en

In

1722 en (a preposition) – properly, in (inside, within); (figuratively) "in the realm (sphere) of," as in the condition (state) in whichsomething operates from the inside (within

πᾶσιν
pasin

All and every part

pas: all, every
Original Word: πᾶς, πᾶσα, πᾶν
Part of Speech: Adjective
Transliteration: pas
Phonetic Spelling: (pas)
Definition: all, every
Usage: all, the whole, every kind of.

E.g
Luke 24:21 Adj-DNP
GRK: καὶ σὺν πᾶσιν τούτοις τρίτην
NAS: besides all this,
KJV: and beside all this, to day
INT: also with all these things third

pás ("each, every") means "all" in the sense of "each (every) part that applies." The emphasis of the total picture then is on "one piece at a time."  365 (ananeóō) then focuses on the part(s) making up the whole – viewing the whole in terms of the individual parts

εἰς
eis

To

eis
Phonetic Spelling: (ice)
Definition: to or into (indicating the point reached or entered, of place, time, purpose, result)
Usage: to,  into, in, unto, upon, towards, for, among.

E.g
Matthew 2:8 Prep
GRK: πέμψας αὐτοὺς εἰς Βηθλεὲμ εἶπεν
KJV: he sent them to Bethlehem, and said,
INT: having sent them to Bethlehem he said

ὑμᾶς.
hymas

You

su: you (early mod. Eng. thou)
Original Word: σύ, σοῦ, σοί, σέ
Part of Speech: Personal Pronoun
Transliteration: su
Phonetic Spelling: (soo)
Definition: you (early mod. Eng. thou)
Usage: you

So why are liars involved in bible translations?
Why is 2 corinthians 11:6 mistranslated by liars?
Why for 500 years has this been allowed? 
Why have all the greek experts here allowed it?
Judgment shall be swift on babylon.
He judges and makes war and his name is The Word Of God.

Comment: I don’t think it’s as sinister as you make it out to be, @TomSacks. Also consider that we are wrapping up and almost at the end of the age according to the Essene calendar, we have less than 50 years to go to year 7,000 since Creation so according to Daniel knowledge will increase. We are privileged to have a veil removed so we can see much more and our lines of communication is drastically faster internationally. especially in light of more recent archaeological discoveries we can be more certain than others were. I sense your ardent passion but don’t switch to the flesh keep in the spirit.

Comment: @Tom Again you show a complete lack of Greek knowledge and quoting the Strong's definitions in a series is not exegesis and neither is it how the verse should be translated. While there is not always agreement here, so far no one has been arrogant enough to suggest the entire Church has gotten it wrong for 500 years and now the person with no formal Greek education is going to set us all straight.

Comment: And the same enemy used to forbid access to the word now just says things are off topic rofl.

Comment: A question about "why does translation X translate text Y this way when Z does it differently" would be perfectly on topic. If you'd like to [edit] this to me a simple question instead of a polemic rant it would be on topic.

Comment: @TomSacks I tried following your thought progression, however what do you think 2 corinthians 11:6 actually says?

Answer (score 1):

How can a Bible teacher compete against someone who feels that "GOD SHOWED ME AND CORRECTED" the translations of the Bible that have been accepted for centuries? We are not talking about differences of certain aspects of the verses but someone who thinks the church has gotten them completely wrong. There are differences between some of the translations, sometimes significant ones, but this is a different class of disagreement.

**I may be wrong but it this your basic proposition?**

1. Paul inserts a secret test into the text of 1 Corinthians 5:5, to see if they will bite and kick the man out of the church.
2. They do bite, which indicates they have fallen pray to the "yeast of the pharisee."
3. Then according to you, Paul reveals to them the test in 2 Cor 11:6.
4. Then according to you the Church hid the fact of the test by the propagation of a false translation of the text in 2 Cor. 11:6.

Here is a question: If the text had been hidden in translation. How were you able to find it when countless other translators, including those who are opposed to the Vatican as are most fundamentalists, missed it? Did all fundamentalists miss it? Surely there would have been at least one or two who have written extensively on Greek going back over the centuries. It is hard to imagine someone like Dean Burgon would have missed such an important issue. I know Dean Burgon had a tone that was argumentative but beneath it all he was an excellent Greek scholar. He missed it too?

Enough of the criticism--I'll provide some teaching through the hard work of exegesis.

In 1 Cor 5:5 here are some exegetical points to remember about the text.

1. You are right about one thing, the context was the man who had been committing adultery with his father's wife.
2. In the context of 1 Cor 5:3-5 the judgment that Paul exercised was the kind of temporal judgment that was given to him as an apostle. You could argue that Paul was following through on the commands of Jesus.

In Matthew 18:15-17 Jesus said:

> > 15 Moreover if thy brother shall trespass against thee, go and tell him his fault between thee and him alone: if he shall hear thee, thou hast gained thy brother. 16 But if he will not hear thee, then take with thee one or two more, that in the mouth of two or three witnesses every word may be established. 17 And if he shall neglect to hear them, tell it unto the church: **but if he neglect to hear the church, let him be unto thee as an heathen man and a publican.** (Matthew 18:15-17)

Jesus wasn't testing anyone or have we gotten that passage wrong too? Jesus was laying the groundwork for the principles that would govern church discipline. That is why Paul tells the church at Corinth--"1 Cor. 5:2 And ye are puffed up, and have not rather mourned, that he that hath done this deed might be taken away from among you." He saw their unwillingness to judge (as earthly judges) the sinner and to turn him over to the enemy for chastisement.

- Under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit, Paul reveals the principle that Jesus did not say, but it still applies to the context of Corinth. Know ye not that a little leaven leaveneth the whole lump?
- In 1 Cor 5:5 Paul is speaking of the destruction of his human body, but apparently he was a saved individual, and Paul knew that the man's spirit would be saved even if he died. This fits with his explanation that some of the believers in Corinth had died because they shamed the Lord's Supper. There is an example of a poor translation, 1 Cor. 11:29 the KJV has damnation when it should be judgment or even better earthly judgment.
- Paul was not trying to present a false gospel to test the Corinthians, he was following the Lord Jesus and the commands he had given to the disciples, which the Corinthians had failed to follow at first.

What happened? They followed the Lord, and Paul by having him removed from the local church. Then in what we would all want to see, the sinner turned from his wickedness and Paul learned of this too.

> > 2 Cor. 2:1-11
> >
> > 1 But I determined this with myself, that I would not come again to you in heaviness. 2 For if I make you sorry, who is he then that maketh me glad, but the same which is made sorry by me? 3 And I wrote this same unto you, lest, when I came, I should have sorrow from them of whom I ought to rejoice; having confidence in you all, that my joy is the joy of you all. 4 For out of much affliction and anguish of heart I wrote unto you with many tears; not that ye should be grieved, but that ye might know the love which I have more abundantly unto you. 
> >     5 But if any have caused grief, he hath not grieved me, but in part: that I may not overcharge you all. 6 Sufficient to such a man is this punishment, which was inflicted of many. 7 So that contrariwise ye ought rather to forgive him, and comfort him, lest perhaps such a one should be swallowed up with overmuch sorrow. 8 Wherefore I beseech you that ye would confirm your love toward him. 9 For to this end also did I write, that I might know the proof of you, whether ye be obedient in all things. 10  To whom ye forgive any thing, I forgive also: for if I forgave any thing, to whom I forgave it, for your sakes forgave I it in the person of Christ; 11 Lest Satan should get an advantage of us: for we are not ignorant of his devices.

- 2 Cor. 2:9 does suggest that Paul was writing to see what they would do in the case of the man in adultery: 9 For to this end also did I write, **that I might know the proof of you, whether ye be obedient in all things.** It is ended with a purpose clause that suggest that he was trying to see if they would be obedient. Not obedient to the Paul because in 1 Cor 5, Paul says they were to act in the "name of our Lord Jesus Christ." What 2 Cor 2:9 is suggesting that he wrote to see if they would obey the commands of the Lord Jesus Christ in his demand to treat the person as if they were outside the church.
- Now that he knows they will follow the Lord, and since the man had he calls on them to forgive the man and to bring him back into the church. While it is an argument from silence it seems likely that Paul had learned of the man's repentance just as he had heard of the man's sin. Nevertheless he stated that he had suffered enough and that it was time to forgive him and to restore him to fellowship.

What about 2 Cor. 11:6? This passage has absolutely nothing to do with the previous issue of the man. In 2 Cor 11, Paul speaks of his folly. What was his folly? It was explained previously in 2 Cor 10. It was his abasement of himself for their sake by not exercising his authority and not giving in to those who look on the outward appearance.

Comment: @Tom This is not a discussion and debate site. Comments are not for arguing against answers. Don't.

Comment: You here opposing the truth have been proven to have done so.

Comment: Gods own word testifies against your false translation of it.

Comment: As such you are acting as enemies of the truth and will be judged for it by Jesus Christ.

Comment: So on one post you argue that no believer will be judged and yet here your claim that here I will be judged.  On what basis, I disagree with you and your belief that all of Church history has gotten it wrong and you with no formal Greek training has gotten right.

Comment: Tom let us remember Romans 2:8 "But to them that are contentious, and do not obey the truth, but obey unrighteousness, indignation and wrath,".....let us not be contentious likely to start heated arguments but let us be calm and relaxed trusting in God, the truth does not need anyone to fight for it, if what you preach and teach is truth and sound doctrine, those that love the truth will see that.